# Verifying the contents of list of dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries `l1`:

```
l1 = [
    {'name':'Omer','fname':'ghaffar','sid':1},
    {'name':'zoya','fname':'sattar','sid':2}
]
```

I'm trying to verify whether some content exists in `l1`. For example, I want to check if the `name` and `sid` is the same as the input values (`a1` and `a2`), then it should display "valid user" along with the values.

My code:

```
a1 = input("name ")
a2 = input("sid ")
for e in l1:
    if e['name'] == a1 and e['sid'] == a2:
        print("valid user")
        break
    else:
        print("invalid user")
```

The result I'm getting with the above code is:

```
name Omer
sid 1
invalid user
invalid user
```

I expect the result to be:

```
name Omer
sid 1
valid user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your condition to:

```
if e['name'] == a1 and e['sid'] == int(a2):
```

This is because by default `input` reads as string, so when you compare string with an integer, it's always a `False`.

Alternatively, you could also cast at the time you read from user also:

```
a2 = int(input("sid "))
```

---

Also note that your code keeps on printing `'invalid user'` for an invalid entry or a valid entry that comes later in the list. To avoid this, you can add `else` to `for` instead of `if`:

```
a1 = input("name ")
a2 = input("sid ")

for e in l1:
    if e['name'] == a1 and e['sid'] == int(a2):
        print("valid user")
        break
else:
    print("invalid user")
```